# Is there a way to let Sonarqube know when a build in Jenkins failed?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Is there a way to let Sonarqube know when a build in Jenkins failed? My Sonarqube analysis is triggered by Jenkins downstream of the build of the project. I tried to use the Build Stability Plugin in Sonarqube, but it only works if the build on Jenkins was successful. But I want to show the information that a build failed on Sonarqube's Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Sonar doesn't know about "builds" it just has its analysed versions. Therefore, out of the box there is nothing to support that behavior. It would maybe be possible to build an Addon for sonar which shows information about the current build, but don't know such an addon.

Comment: I thought about writing a Sonar-Plugin too. But isn't there a simpler solution. I think it's quite common to want the build stability shown in Sonarqube.

Comment: @Kris Can't Jenkins handle it for you? For us, Jenkins drives the whole process checking 1) does the build actually build 2) does the Sonarqube analysis highlight any problems, etc. Jenkins emails us if the build fails and its UI shows that the build has failed. Sonar only does the code-quality analysis for us

Comment: @Disco 3: Yes, it can. But we want to have Jenkin's build information and Sonarqube's analysis on one screen. We have a monitor at the wall which shows the Sonarqube dashboard of all projects we are currently working on. :)